# How to Show Form On 2nd and 3rd Monitor in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-monitors

I have 3 Monitors Connected With One PC. I have a WPF Application. I want to open one form of this Application on 3rd Screen. How i can open it on 3rd Screen. ?

Thanks

Comment: Error 1 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think WPF don't have any Method Location and Screen Class

Comment: Did you add the 'using System.Windows.Forms;' reference (in code behind)?

Comment: @Odrai added but still not working... Error still 

Error 1 The type 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a':

Comment: I only have this code. 
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;

Comment: @HenkHolterman i already added using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yes added that as well. 

Error 1 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)